# dnsmasq on an interface connected to a Linux bridge not working

Tags: linux, networking, routes, bridge, dnsmasq

I have a few Ubuntu VMs. One with a DHCP server and the rest would be clients.

On the DHCP server,

- I created a Linux bridge (br-1)
- Assigned static IP to eth1.
- Attached the interface eth1 to bridge br-1.
- Ran dnsmasq on eth1.

Then from a client I ran 'dhclient -v eth1' in the hope to get an IP. But it does not work. However, if I just move the eth1 out of the bridge and try a dhclient from  one of my client VMs the client gets an IP assigned properly. Am not sure why. Can anyone please point out what am I missing here ?

I also tried the following --

- Assigning the bridge (br-1) a static IP in the subnet range as eth1.
- Adding default gateway for bridge IP.
- Adding default gateway for eth1 IP.
- Disabling IP tables fully.

None of the above helped. I *have* to use the Linux bridge as it is part of a larger requirement.

Any pointers would be of great help.

Thanks !

Comment: bridge should be connected by two interfaces, you'd just join eth1 to br-1, but where the second one?
Here is a good artical: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge